# XML file validation using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am using DOMDocument for xml file validation. It takes more than 30 minutes in validating a 67MB xml file. Is there any other way to improve this checking time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of XML file are you reading that's 67MB? I'm surprised PHP isn't running out of memory with a file that large.

Comment: XML file contains our own internal data :) and PHP is not running out of memory. We have given plenty of memory to PHP and there is no such memory limit error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)? I recall this one as being pretty decent, though I don't think I tested it on anything as large as 67 MB.

Comment: I tried but its not working. All its saying valid atleast DOMDocument detects errors.

$xml = new XMLReader(); 
$xml->open("../output.xml");
if($xml->setSchema('../schema.xsd')) {
 if($xml->isValid()) {
  echo 'Valid';
 }
 else {
  echo 'Not valid';
 }
}
else {
 echo 'Failed to load xml schema';
}

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $oXml = new SimpleXMLElement($sXml, LIBXML_DTDVALID);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $aErrors = libxml_get_errors();
}
```